# HTML Table width auto in fluid layout and nowrap

Tags: jquery, css, html, layout

What I want it the table width to be the width of the elements into the TDs (text or inputs or selects). CSS table width 100% is not the solution, and width auto is not neither. What is the solution then?

Example

CSS

```
table{width:10px;} //this is the trick I am using but there must be a better solution

td{border:1px solid black;white-space:nowrap;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Some text... </td>
        <td>May 2011</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Another text... </td>
        <td>April 2011</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is working but I do not thing to set the table width to 10px is the solution

Here is a demo Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rM47m/493/

Comment: You fiddle has 4 columns....not three and I'm not sure I understand what it is you are asking for

Comment: The layout of the site is 3 columns but I am talking about the table in the center column, it may have 4 or 10 TDs

Comment: This still makes no sense...what exactly are you trying to do...limit the table to the width of the center column? You need to demo the WHOLE problem.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: The solution is width: auto;
            height: auto;